# How do we treat the header while 8-alignment malloc implementation

Tags: c

I am trying to build a mymalloc in c programming with 8-byte alignment.
But I find a problem, if there is a 4-byte header, and 8-byte payload(malloced data),

Do we have to malloc 16-byte to match the alignment or do we only care about the alignment of payload?

Comment: So your malloc has a pointer to the header on a four-byte boundary and the pointer passed to the caller has to be on an eight-bye boundary?

Comment: Could you explain it further? `we only care about the alignment of payload?` Who is "we"? The user of the library cares only about payload. You write your own mymalloc, so you can decide if you need your header to be aligned or not.

Comment: Yes we have to allocate 16 bytes if the header is 8byte aligned

Comment: @JerryJeremiah I am trying to make a block that contains both header+payloads, so if I am curious if I have 12 bytes total, do I have to malloc 16-byte for alignment?

Comment: @KamilCuk Can I ask how does normal malloc treat with the alignment?

Comment: That depends on which "normal malloc" you want to look at - every "C standard library implementation" comes with it's own implementation of malloc. You can inspect: https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/malloc/malloc.c#L1059 https://github.com/eblot/newlib/blob/master/newlib/libc/stdlib/mallocr.c#L79 https://github.com/esmil/musl/blob/master/src/malloc/malloc.c#L356 also jemalloc , dlmalloc, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Per C 2018 7.22.3 1, `malloc` returns memory sufficiently aligned for any fundamental alignment requirement. The C implementation may define its greatest fundamental alignment, and it is sufficient for all of the basic, enumerator, and pointer types and arrays, structures, and unions whose members have fundamental alignment requirements and for all complete object types in the standard C library. You can find the fundamental alignment with `_Alignof (max_align_t)`. Let’s call that *F*.

If you are using `malloc` to get memory to be used in your `mymalloc`, you will use a few bytes of it (less than *F*) for your own data, and you wish the address you return to have alignment *F*, then you need to ask `malloc` for *F* bytes more than the amount of memory the caller requested. That is because `malloc` will return some address *A* with alignment *F* (or better), and, after putting your data there, you have to return some address greater than that to the user. The next address with alignment *F* is *A*+*F*, so the memory block at *A* will have *F* bytes followed by the user’s data. Hence you need to ask `malloc` for *F* bytes plus the amount the caller requested.